# What is the etymology of "yonks"?

Tags: etymology, origin-unknown

How did we come to say "yonks" meaning a long period of time?

> "I haven't been to the cinema in yonks."

Etymonline has nothing and [Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/yonks?q=yonks) has:

> noun:
>   British informal: 
>   a very long time:
>   I haven’t seen him for yonks
>
> 1960s: origin unknown; perhaps related to donkey's years (see donkey)

If it has indeed spawned from "donkey's years", when and whereso?

Comment: For the record, this is the first time I've seen (and I still have never heard) that word. It appears to be completely unAmerican. As for the meaning, it seems to be a [negative polarity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) quantifier like _in weeks_, essentially a temporal [squatitive](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/squatitives.html), like _diddleysquat_ or _bugger all_.

Comment: +1 for squatitive, but no I don't think it is one. It is certainly negative polarity, but at the same time it implies that beyond the "yonks" the positive did hold. You wouldn't say _I haven't seen him for yonks_ if you've never seen him in your life.

Comment: @JohnLawler, it does not really have negative polarity—saying, “I’ve known him for yonks” works just fine (just like with ‘weeks’), though of course “*I’ve known him in yonks” does not. That’s not a property of ‘yonks’ itself, though.

Comment: It's ***in** weeks* that's the NPI; ***for** weeks* isn't. Can you say _in yonks_? Is _He hasn't been here in yonks_ grammatical? I'd thought it was a nonce coinage like "donkey's years"; can you say _He's lived there for donkey's years/a coon's age_ grammatically? If not, then they're different from _yonks_.

Comment: I've certainly heard both "in yonks" and "for yonks".  I'm not sure if I can decide on which is most common.

Comment: @JohnLawler it may surprise you to find that English came from England, and as such it is itself *unAmerican*. It's not a personal attack, I just find it funny that some Americans take ownership of English as if it originated in America. 'Yonks' is very common to me, as an English person.

Comment: Merely a dialectal specification. I find it amusing that you believe I'm claiming ownership. I don't own any languages except my own; and by the same token, I'm not responsible for anybody else's language, or uses of it, or interpretations of it.

Comment: @John: But _in_ + [any denoter of a time in the past] has negative polarity.

Comment: Oh, no, the NPI has very specific object requirements. For instance, while _in weeks/months/ages/donkey's years/a coon's age/a long time_ are NPIs, _in minutes/seconds/the month of February 2005/the Mauve Decade/his lifetime_ aren't, whether they're past or present.

Comment: I just ran across a piece from a Terry Pratchett novel (_Thief of Time_) that may shed some ..er.. light on the topic. A monk and a novice are talking and the monk comments on something that happens **very** frequently. Novice: "Has it been happening while we've been talking?" Monk: "Millions of times. An oodleplex of times, probably." Novice: "How many's that?" Monk: "It's one of the abbot's words. It means more numbers than you can imagine in a yonk." Novice: "What's a yonk?" Monk: "A very long time."

Comment: Cockney rhyming slang? Seems likely...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OED says the origin of *yonks* is unknown and has it from 1968 in the *Daily Mail*:

> I rang singer Julie Driscoll... She said: ‘I haven't heard from you for yonks.’

The *Shorter Slang Dictionary* (Partridge, Beale, Fergusson, 1994) agrees it's from the 1960s and suggests:

> Probably from years, perhaps influenced by donkey’s years.

*Donkey's years* (also *donkeys' years*) is a play on "donkey's ears" which are long, therefore a long time. The OED has it from 1916 but I found an earlier example in the [Australian Trove newspaper archive](http://nla.gov.au/nla.news-article68716515) in "THE WAISTCOAT MAKER" (1905, October 24), West Gippsland Gazette:

> 'Thank 'heaven fer that,' I says. 'I want 
>   to git back to work. It seems **donkeys'
>   years** to me.'

Comment: I've sent this antedating to the [OED](http://global.oup.com/uk/oedsubform/).

Comment: Huh, never thought about the length of a donkey's ears in relation to the phrase. +1 for teaching me something interesting!

Comment: I was born in the 1960s, in England, and my childhood recollection of my father's usage of "yonks" is that it was a corruption of Donkeys' Years, hence my upvote.

Answer (score 5):

The most plausible explanation I have found is [here](http://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-1757,00.html).

It is most likely an abbreviated spoonerism of *donkey's (y)ears*:
*yonkeys' dears*.

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-yon1.htm) reviews this word, take a look at it. A few quotes from it:

> Many people — including Paul Beale and Mr Stuart-Mogg — say they believe it’s a convoluted acronym, formed from “Year, mONth, weeKS”...

...

> A few reference books suggest instead that it might be from donkey’s years, also meaning a long time. This sounds quite daft on first hearing, but if you think about it, you can see how the onk of donkey might just have been prefixed by the y of years, perhaps as conscious or unconscious back slang.

Answer (score -2):

I have used the full expression 'yonkey's dears' many times in both England and America and it is always understood. The real mystery is why anyone thinks it's a mystery.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Sallie.  Note that OP (original poster) was asking for etymology.